# 1 solution, many projects with overlapping dlls, is it possible to create a project just for those common .dlls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference, assemblies

I have a solution with several different projects in it. Many of these projects reference the same .dlls in the .csproj files. In order to cut down on the number of .dlls I'm copying would it be possible to create another project in this solution that references the common .dlls, then have my other projects reference that project?

Comment: Yes of course, but unless you are going to wrap the functionality exposed by each of these DLL's in your new project, I fail to see how this would help. Alternatively, you can add DLL's with shared functionality into the GAC in order to have it globally available to your projects.

Comment: You'd still have to copy those dependencies of your "unified" project dll. Just set your references to "Copy to Local" and VS will handle copying what is needed for you.

Comment: If you use the classes of common DLLs in your project, you will have to explicitly add reference to the common DLLs there... So you can't really avoid the situation.

Comment: If your solution is just getting too big, it's entirely possible to split it into multiple solutions and for the high-level code to just reference the DLLs produced by the low-level code.